# Join a Column with SELECT query in PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Need this equivalent outcome on PostgreSQL on this MySQL [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2e5c/36).

```
select id, 'ID1' from supportContacts
```

Idea is to Join a Column with table name and row values equals to ID1.

Executing the same query on PostgreSQL gives the desired row values but gives  `?column? uknown` as column name.

Which PostgreSQL query will give the exact output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a *column alias* to assign a *name* of your choosing. Else the system applies defaults.
To assign a *type*, use an explicit *cast*. I cast to `text` here:

```
SELECT id, 'ID1'::text AS "ID1" FROM supportContacts
```

Or use the SQL standard [`cast()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-GENERIC) to make it portable:

```
SELECT id, cast('ID1' AS varchar) AS "ID1" FROM "supportContacts"
```

For portability, make sure that MySQL runs with [`SET sql_mode = 'ANSI'`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi).

Also, unquoted CaMeL-case names like `supportContacts` are cast to lower case in PostgreSQL.  Use `"supportContacts"` or `supportcontacts` depending on the actual table name.

Start by reading the excellent manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) for basics about identifiers.

Comment: What about MySQL will the default TYPE be 'text'?

Answer (score 0):

You can find answer in SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/f9ece/2)