# Combining two SQL SELECT statements on the same table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-order-by, union

I would like to combine these two SQL queries:

```
SELECT * FROM "Contracts" WHERE 
"productType" = 'RINsell' AND
"clearTime" IS NULL AND
"holdTime" IS NOT NULL 
 ORDER BY "generationTime";
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM "Contracts" WHERE 
"productType" = 'RINsell' AND
"clearTime" IS NULL AND
"holdTime" IS NULL 
 ORDER BY "contractLimitPrice";
```

When I run each statement, I get exactly the results I want, I would just like both results sequentially. My first thought was to use UNION ALL since this selections will be disjoint but I found that you can't use a `UNION` after an `ORDER BY`. I've searched quite a bit and most people suggest doing the `ORDER BY` after the `UNION` but each query has different `ORDER BY` conditions.

Comment: Have you tried SELECT (query1) UNION ALL (query2)?

Comment: I don't follow; like:
`SELECT( * FROM "Contracts" WHERE 
"productType" = 'RINsell' AND
"clearTime" IS NULL AND
"holdTime" IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY "generationTime")
UNION ALL
SELECT( * FROM "Contracts" WHERE 
"productType" = 'RINsell' AND
"clearTime" IS NULL AND
"holdTime" IS NULL 
ORDER BY "contractLimitPrice");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the results of the first query before the results of the second, you can remove   `holdtime` from the where clause, and use an order by like

```
order by
  case when holdTime is not null then 0 else 1 end, --first query comes first
  case when holdTime is not null --different orders for queries
       then generationTime
       else contractLimitPrice
  end
```

Comment: Thanks! I've never done anything with SQL before so it took me a second to figure it out:
`SELECT * FROM "Contracts" WHERE 
"productType" = 'RINsell' AND
"clearTime" IS NULL
order by
  case when "holdTime" is not null then 0 else 1 end, --first query comes first
  case when "holdTime" is not null --different orders for queries
       then "generationTime"
       else "contractLimitPrice"
  end;`

Answer (score 0):

> ... but I found that you can't use a `UNION` after an `ORDER BY`.

Well, you didn't look hard enough:

```
(
SELECT *
FROM   "Contracts"
WHERE  "productType" = 'RINsell'
AND    "clearTime" IS NULL
AND    "holdTime" IS NOT NULL 
ORDER  BY "generationTime"
)
UNION ALL
)
SELECT *
FROM   "Contracts"
WHERE  "productType" = 'RINsell'
AND    "clearTime" IS NULL
AND    "holdTime" IS NULL 
ORDER  BY "contractLimitPrice"
)
```

Note the parentheses. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION)

> (`ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` can be attached to a subexpression if it is
>   enclosed in parentheses. Without parentheses, these clauses will be
>   taken to apply to the result of the `UNION`, not to its right-hand input
>   expression.)

Closely related answer:
[Sum results of a few queries and then find top 5 in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528787/sum-results-of-a-few-queries-and-then-find-top-5-in-sql/8528920#8528920)

Aside: I really would [get rid of those CaMeL case identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744580/join-a-column-with-select-query-in-postgresql/13744716#13744716). Your life is much easier with all-lower case legal identifiers in Postgres.