# Selecting two columns in same table multiple times

Tags: sql, postgresql, union, union-all, sql-limit

I am trying to use the below query that shows **country** and **population** of *second most and second least populous* country. I figured out a way to select the population for those countries but I can't find any good way to implement selection of country names.

```
Select  Max(population) 
From country Where population < (Select max (population) From country)
Union
Select Min(population)
From country where population > (select Min(population) from country) ;
```

I found a way for selecting country and population for second most/second least populous country but problem is I can't use `union` on two selects with 2 ORDER BY (one in each select).

Any idea what I can do to solve my problem?
*Note: Im using Postgres*

Comment: Much better implemented using `OFFSET 1 LIMIT 1` and an `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from (
    select country, population
    from
        (
            select country, population
            from country
            order by population
            offset 1 limit 1
        ) s

    union

    select country, population
    from
        (
            select country, population
            from country
            order by population desc
            offset 1 limit 1
        ) q
) s
```

Answer (score 1):

By using window function, you can do it simply like this:

```
with t as (
  select population,
         row_number() over (order by population desc) mx,
         row_number() over (order by population asc) mn
  from country)
select 'second most population', population from t where mx = 2
union all
select 'second least population', population from t where mn = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution :

```
(SELECT name, population 
FROM country 
ORDER BY population Desc 
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
) 
UNION
(
SELECT name, population 
FROM country 
ORDER BY population Asc 
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1);
```

All I needed was parentheses...

Answer (score 0):

*Much* simpler and faster:

```
(
SELECT population
FROM   country
ORDER  BY 1
OFFSET 1
LIMIT  1
)
UNION ALL
)
SELECT population
FROM   country
ORDER  BY 1 DESC
OFFSET 1
LIMIT  1
);
```

**Yes**, you can use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` for individual legs of a `UNION` query. Just use parentheses. Details:
[Combining two SQL SELECT statements on the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575303/combining-two-sql-select-statements-on-the-same-table/22578432#22578432)

Be sure to have an **index** on `population` to make this very fast for bigger tables.

And use [**`UNION ALL`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION), since you do not want to fold duplicates. Faster and actually *correct*.